# Rutas en laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

En la aplicación que realizo, las rutas desde el servidor virtual (Homestead), funcionan sin ningún problema, pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación en entorno local, para una lan, las rutas no cargan, es decir, me sale que no existen los archivos.

Alguna sugerencia, por favor!!!

Comment: ¿qué error te aparece?

Comment: El clasico...


Not Found

The requested URL /SisPlaniC/public/login was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Limitaste caché e hiciste `composer du`?

Comment: Si!!!! Ya lo hice y sigue igual.

Comment: Necesitamos más información, de la diferencia entre homestead y el servidor local. Algún motivo para no utilizar solo homestead? Me causa mucha curiosidad eso.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Homestead para desarrollo, luego lo pasaré a un servidor local para una lan, a la que se conectan aprox 30 usuarios.

O me recomiendas que lo deje en homestead para producción.???

Comment: No, homestead no fue diseñado para producción. Realmente depende como administras tus instancias. Puedes utilizar una herramienta que automatice la instalación de tus dependencias, puedes basarte en el script que usa homestead.

Comment: Exacto. Ya instalé todas las dependencias, pero aun me sigue dando el mismo error.

Es extraño, porque estando bajo la version 5.3, no me generaba este detalle.

Comment: Que servidor usas? Apache Nginx [...]? Puedes agregar la configuración del sitio?

Comment: Uso apache!!.. Instale una version limpia de laravel 5.4 y va bien. El detalle se sigue presentando con aplicacion ya desarrollada.

Comment: Deberias de poner algun ejemplo de que ruta o url no te esta dando y que tipo de error te esta dando, muchas veces me ocurría ese tipo de error en url's que ponia *<a href="my/ruta">hacia mi ruta</a>*, lo cual esta mal lo correcto seria *<a href="{{url('my/ruta')}}">hacia mi ruta</a>*, algo asi, haber si pones un ejemplo